# Inserting record in table results in error message

Tags: delphi-2010

When I want to insert records in my table in the database I get this error message: There are fewer columns in the insert statement than specified in the values clause. This is my SQL statement:

```
dm.qr_emp.SQl.Add( 'insert into emp_per(nom, prenom, date_naiss1, cle_ccp,nomf,prenomf,' +
  'lieu_naiss,sex,adr,id_corps,id_fonction,id_categ,montant_resp,' + 'compte_ccp,etat,sal_base,id_grade,id_banque,id_degree,sal_unique,' +'pfc,iep,num_social,sal_principale,ind,salaire,montant_irg,' +
  'ss,nbr_enfant,nbr_enfant_sup,bource_f,irg,retenue) '
);
dm.qr_emp.SQL.Add
('values('+quotedstr(edit1.Text)+', '+quotedstr(edit2.Text)+','+quotedstr(formatdatetime('yyyy-dd-mm',datetimepicker1.DateTime))+', '+

edit4.Text+','+quotedstr(edit5.Text)+','+quotedstr(edit3.Text)+','+quotedstr(edit6.Text)+','+quotedstr(ComboBox3.Text)+','+quotedstr(edit8.Text)+','+ inttostr(id_corps)+','+ inttostr(id_fonction)+', 
'+quotedstr(edit10.Text)+','+floattostr(salair_responsabilite)+','+quotedstr(edit7.Text)+','+quotedstr(ComboBox5.Text)+','+floattostr(salaire_base)+','+ inttostr(id_grade)+','+ inttostr(id_banque)+','+

inttostr(id_degree)+','+quotedstr(ComboBox8.Text)+','+ 
floattostr(pfc)+','+quotedstr(edit15.Text)+','+quotedstr(edit13.Text)+','+ 
floattostr(sal_principale)+','+floattostr(ind)+','+quotedstr(edit20.text)+',+'+floattostr(montant_irg)+','+floattostr(ss)+', '+(edit23.Text)+', 
'+quotedstr(edit26.Text)+','+floattostr(boursef)+','+quotedstr(edit21.Text)+','+
floattostr(retenu)+')'); 

dm.qr_emp.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: What is the actual error message? Also, this code has SQL Injection attack vectors on `Edit4` and `Edit23`. You should be using a **parameterized query** instead of formatting parameter values manually.

Comment: Stop concatenating your SQL and use parameters, and you won't have these sorts of issues. As to the specific error, you have to have a value (even if it's NULL) to match every single column in your INSERT statement. This is basic SQL, and applies whether you're using Delphi or something else.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to insert a record, the number of columns have to be the same as the number of inserted values. For instance:

```
INSERT INTO Employees(Name, City, AccountNumber)
VALUES ("John", "London", "0098737602230")
```

The next statements would fail for example, because the number of column names and inserted values do not match.

```
INSERT INTO Employees(Name, City)
VALUES ("John", "London", "0098737602230")

INSERT INTO Employees(Name, City, AccountNumber)
VALUES ("John", "London")
```

I would advise to structure your code a bit. The current statement is not readable by humans and will lead to errors.

Comment: the problem is  data type not the number of columns

Comment: That's not what the error message says (or did the translation from French to English go wrong?).

Comment: @ميارجوري: Your question says *There are fewer columns in the insert statement than specified in the values clause.* That's not a data type issue - it's not enough columns in the VALUE to match what's in the INSERT, as Bourke has said.